# Netbeans + CodeSniffer installation. Windows command prompt shows false error

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, pear, phpcodesniffer

I have been trying to install CodeSniffer on NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 (Build 201411181905) and am following these instructions

"Install PHP_CodeSniffer, PHPMD, PHP_Depend and PHPCPD. The preferred way is the installation with the PEAR installer (You have to run these commands as root on *nix, respectively Administrator on Windows systems)."

```
pear config-set auto_discover 1
pear install --alldeps pear/PHP_CodeSniffer
pear install --alldeps phpmd/PHP_PMD
pear install --alldeps pdepend/PHP_Depend
pear install --alldeps phpunit/phpcpd
pear config-set auto_discover 0
```

**Source**:

http://blog.florianwolters.de/tutorial/2012/05/03/Integrate-tools-for-static-PHP-code-analyses-into-NetBeans-7.x/

The first command "pear config-set auto_discover 1" got me to this

[image]

which says both "php_ibm_db2.dll and php_pdo_informix.dll" could not be found.

On enteing the second command "pear install --alldeps pear/PHP_CodeSniffer" again got me to the same error (refer to the image up top)

On checking manually, I found both php_ibm_db2.dll and php_pdo_informix.dll are present but somehow it could not be detected/found.

[image]

Why this false error and how do I move forward?

**Note** I have already installed php pear on my xampp.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and fix my extensions or disable them in case they are not needed. Do you really use IBM DB2 and Informix? If so - install clients for these, if not - disable from the php.ini and try again.